# pip install flask results in bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, pip, virtualenv

```
(taskr_env)dhcp-07-415-562-00:flasktaskr CB$ pip install flask==0.10.1
-bash: /Users/CB/Dropbox (Personal)/Python_Practice/flasktaskr/taskr_env/bin/pip: 
"/Users/CB/Dropbox: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have virtualenv activated and I am not sure why this is happening. 
It seems that the issue is because "Dropbox (Personal)" has a space and parentheses so it cannot find it. I don't want to change the name as it loses sync with my dropbox account.

Please help

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that there is a space in the path leading to your virtual environment. Note that it is trying to use the path up to the space as the interpreter, instead of the entire thing. If you can use a path with no spaces the problem will go away.